# Running query in Pipeline in Azure-DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add an Azure-DevOps query to a pipeline,
Is there an option to put a query in a yaml file?
If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question to include what you want to accomplish and provide an example of what you've tried. For example, what do you mean by "query"? Do you mean WIQL?

Comment: Hi Ariel, any update? did my post help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you could run a [rest api for query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) via powershell script or something like that in a pipeline task to do it.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=7.0
```

Powershell Script

```
# Define organization base url, PAT and API version variables

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}"

$pat = "{pat}"

$queryString = "api-version=7.0"



# Create header with PAT

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

# Get the list of all projects in the organization

$projectsUrl = "$orgUrl/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?$queryString"

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json



write-host $result
```

If you are going to echo the specific element from the query result, you could modify the `$result` line with below

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty {your element}

write-host $result
```

You could also [create a query with rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP), and with the similar powershell script to put into pipeline.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=7.0
```